# Real Analysis Proof Verification

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Suppose $\alpha(x)$ is a strictly monotone increasing function on the interval $[a, b]$. Let ${x_n}$be a sequence with a $\leq x_n \leq b$ for all $n \geq 1$. If $\lim_{n\to\infty} \alpha(x_n) = \alpha(b)$, show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = b$.

Solution:

Since $\alpha(x)$ is strictly monotone increasing on the interval $[a,b]$, $\alpha^{-1}$ exists and is strictly monotone increasing on $[a,b]$ as well. Let $y_n = \alpha(x_n)$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \alpha(x_n) = \alpha(b)$, there exists infinite terms $y_n$ such that $\alpha(b) - \epsilon \leq y_n \leq  \alpha(b) \leq \alpha(b) + \epsilon$. This implies  that there are also infinite terms $x_n$ such that $b - \epsilon \leq x_n \leq  b \leq b + \epsilon$. Hence, by definition, $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = b$.

My problem is that I don't really know how to justify the implication stated above.

Comment: Since $\alpha$ strictly increasing you have $\alpha^{-1}$ strictly increasing. This gives you the implication.

Answer (score 0):

Just showing that there are infinite number of terms with that property does not imply convergence (just consider the sequence $a,b,a,b,a,...$). You must show that for a large enough $n$ all the subsequent terms satisfy this. Here is how it can be done:

Since $\alpha(x_n) \to \alpha(b)$ we know that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $N$ so that when $n>N$ then $\alpha(b) - \epsilon < \alpha(x_n)$ by using that $\alpha$ is increasing.

Now define $x(\epsilon) = \inf \left(x : \alpha(x) > \alpha(b)-\epsilon \right)$

As $\alpha(x)$ is stricktly increasing we have that $x(\epsilon)$ is stricktly decreasing (with $x(0) = b$) and from the definition of $x(\epsilon)$ we have

$\alpha(x(\epsilon)) \leq \alpha(x_n) \leq \alpha(b)$

Using again that $\alpha$ is increasing gives us

$x(\epsilon) \leq x_n \leq b$

As $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0-} x(\epsilon) = b$ the result follows.

Comment: are u referring to supremum here? cos i think infimum is not really strictly decreasing

Comment: I think its correct as it stands. Note that as we decrease $\epsilon$ then $x(\epsilon)$ will increase. You can of course use supremum if you will: $x(\epsilon) = \sup(x:\alpha(x) < \alpha(b) - \epsilon)$ does the same trick.

Comment: btw the strickly increasing comes from the properties of $\alpha$. Inf (or sup) is just used to get hold of the particular value of $x$. If $\alpha$ was continuous we would just put $x$ as the solution of $\alpha(x)=\alpha(b)-\epsilon$

Comment: $x(\epsilon)$ is only _strictly_ decreasing if $\alpha$ is continuous. I see no continuity assumption. But this makes no difference, the argument holds nicely.